# setting minDate and maxDate in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want minDate and maxDate to get set dynamically everytime on selecting the new date

```js
$("#dtpik1").datepicker({
  minDate: "-3M",
  maxDate: '0D',
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  onSelect: function(selected, date, value) {
    var d = new Date()
    var d1 = d.getDate()
    var date2 = $("#dtpik1").datepicker("getDate")
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 30)
    var date3 = $("#dtpik1").datepicker("getDate")

    if (d > date2) {
      $('#dtpik2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-4M' && date3,
        maxDate: date2
      });
      $('#dtpik2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    } else {
      $('#dtpik2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-4M' && date3,
        maxDate: d
      });
      $('#dtpik2').datepicker('setDate', d);
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take time to explain exactly what the problem is, what you've tried to solve it, and what issues you're finding.  All you've done is give a statement of intent, and a block of code, without giving us an idea of what the actual problem your facing is

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? the current date?

Comment: the problem is minDate in not updating onSelect of date

Comment: Your format is not correct either, the spec states "String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today." but you have UPPERCASE M and appending it to a date string ?

Comment: apart from minDate the maxDate is also not working